# Lifecycle hook this.$postLink gives typeerror

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components, angularjs-lifecycle

I'm trying to learn angular 1.5 component and have stumbled into a problem. The following code is my startup layout of my component, which compiles without errors with my gruntjob.

```
angular.module('layout',[]).component('kiHeaderParallax',{
        controller: myController,
        controllerAs: 'comp',
        template:'<div>Yo</div>'
    });

    function myController(){
        this.$postLink(domManipulation);
        console.log('poop');
    }

    function domManipulation(){
        console.log('poop2');
    }


angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['layout']);
    });
```

However I get this typeError when going to the browser:

```
> 1.angular-1.5.5.js:13550TypeError: this.$postLink is not a function
>     at new myController (ki-header-parallax.component.ts:14)
>     at Object.invoke (1.angular-1.5.5.js:4665)
>     at $controllerInit (1.angular-1.5.5.js:10115)
>     at nodeLinkFn (1.angular-1.5.5.js:9033)
>     at compositeLinkFn (1.angular-1.5.5.js:8397)
>     at compositeLinkFn (1.angular-1.5.5.js:8400)
>     at compositeLinkFn (1.angular-1.5.5.js:8400)
>     at publicLinkFn (1.angular-1.5.5.js:8277)
>     at hint.js:1480
>     at 1.angular-1.5.5.js:1751
```

I am using Angular 1.5.5 - so that shouldn't be the issue - any ideas why I can't get my log through?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXQXgN?editors=1010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution

```
this.$postLink = domManipulation;
```

instead of

```
this.$postLink(domManipulation);
```